# List a local directory with chrome extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, filesystems, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to create a chrome extension which scans a local directory for new files ...
However, if I add the file://* permission to the manifest I can access the internal file browser of chrome with

`xmlhttp.open("GET","file://C:/Users/username/Desktop/",false);
xmlhttp.send();
console.log(xmlhttp.response);`

From the response I could extract the file URLs and use them in my extension.

My question is now: Are there other approaches? The above way seems more like a workaround and easily breaks if chrome's file browser is changed ...

Comment: List all directories then read all the files from them and send it to you? It's impossible

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Any time I've had to do something on the local machine from a Chrome extension, I've always created a small program that accepts connections via HTTP, and does the work as a normal program, taking commands with JSON over POST.  This gives you great flexibility, as it essentially allows you to write a Chrome extension that can do anything a desktop program can do.

However, there are great downsides to this, and you should only do it if absolutely necessary.  For instance:

- You can't do this for all operating systems, unless you're going to write an agent for every OS.
- The extension cannot be installed from Google's extension hosting.
- You must [write your own installation program that registers the extension](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/dev/external_extensions.html).
- There are very real security considerations to worry about with this.  You will be opening up a web service that executes commands.  Be **very** sure that you are not exposing the user.  In all reality, if you are making a file browser, you probably are exposing the user.  It will be up to you to fix this security hole, as if you were creating any other web service.

Comment: Your link works but inside of the page they have iframe showing «Aw, Snap! We couldn't find that page», isn’t it the same page as this: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/external_extensions/