# Retrieve image from local drives into website using slimpphp framework

Tags: php, html, image

I want to retrieve images from local `C drive` and display it on my website. Is this possible? I'm quite new to web development and need some help.

I'm able to get the image on the browser by adding `file:///` on the image path but it doesn't show on website when it goes into the project.

I have read through forums saying creating a browser extension or some sort but it is hard to understand.

I've tried to follow these links:
 - [Link 1](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/)
 - [Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18246053/how-can-i-create-a-link-to-a-local-file-on-a-locally-run-web-page)
 - [Link 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8813282/list-a-local-directory-with-chrome-extension)
, but have no succes.

I have a table with rows. After clicking on each rows, it will shows a list of information about that rows data. Im able to retrieve the data regarding the info on the rows data but not the image.

code snippet:
{
  view:"unitlist",
       d:"unitlist",
       uniteBy:function(obj){
       return obj.MovieGenre; //get the obj from table row
        },

template:"#MovieGenre#   Title: #movie_name#, Release Date: #date#,  Rating: #rate#",
}

Comment: why you are tagging this question with `slim` ??

Comment: cause im using slimphp framework. Do you have any idea on this?

Comment: Show us some of your code..

Comment: but your question is not related to `slim`, apply only problem related tags or you think if that tag can possibly related to your problem!!